# Задержка в цикле

Tags: jquery, циклы, javascript

Есть такой код у меня

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 53; i++) {

rand = random(minc, maxc);
$('#comment_chat_'+rand).fadeIn(2000);
                                                                 setTimeout("$('#comment_chat_"+rand+"').fadeIn(600);", 3000);
}
```

хочу выводить блоки `comment_chat_` по очереди через несколько секунд, но при таких раскладах выводится все сразу через н времени. Как это сделать в моем случае ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 53; i++) {

rand = random(minc, maxc);
$('#comment_chat_'+rand).fadeIn(2000+i*100);
                                                                 setTimeout("$('#comment_chat_"+rand+"').fadeIn(600);", 3000+i*100);
}
```

где i*100 задержка в миллисекундах. т.е. для первого элемента 3100мс, второго 3200мс итд

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я именно так и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;

function show() {

    rand = random(minc, maxc);
    $('#comment_chat_' + rand).fadeIn(2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        i++; 
        if (i <= 53) {
           show();
        }        
    }, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pqQZG/ — блоки, по очереди

```
for (var i = 0; i < 53; i++) {
    $('#comment_chat_' + (i + 1))
        .delay(i * 500) // задержка
        .fadeIn(2000)
    ;
}
```